# Inbound calling on Azure Communication Services

Tags: azure, azure-communication-services

Currently, the inbound calling feature is not available on Azure Communication Services. Can someone provide a tentative date for this feature to be added to Communication Services?

Answer (score 1):

Inbound calling will be available as a bot framework feature launching in preview state before spring.

Once there is further public information to share, we will try to circle back to this thread to share the information.